# g++ -lcurl says its not found, but I can see it in ldconfig -p

Tags: c++, linker

I am trying to build some software on a brand new install of CentOS 5.5

My compile line is :

```
 g++ -I ../common/ -I ../readers/ -I ../writers/ -I /home/dcole/software/xerces-c-3.1.1/src -O3 -Wall -fopenmp -fPIC -o chipper chipper.cpp  -L/usr/lib64/ ../../lib/IDT.a ../../lib/Linux/libxerces-c.a -lcurl -lidn -ldl -lssl ../../lib/Linux/libfftw3f.a  -lpthread -lm
```

and I am getting

```
[exec] /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
 [exec] collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Even though I can actually see the lib

```
$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep curl
        libcurl.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.3
        libcurl.so.3 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libcurl.so.3
```

So why cant g++ see it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At link time, `-lcurl` tells the linker to look for `libcurl.so`.

From there, the SONAME within the library (`libcurl.so.3`) is embedded into the executable, and that's the filename that is searched for when executing.

You have `libcurl.so.3` but may be lacking `libcurl.so`, which is needed for development.

What is your distribution?  Usually there will be a second package with development headers/libraries, separate from the runtime bits.

Comment: centos 5.5 - so you thinkt hey did not install the development package?

Comment: @Derek: Yes.  On CentOS, (lib)cURL is installed by package `curl`, while its development headers and libraries are installed by packed `curl-devel`.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file from any source `/usr/lib/libcurl.so` and place it in `/usr/lib/`, then try to compile. It will work out.

Comment: -1 Why proposing a bad-hack when a cleaner solution was already approved?